# Km/liter or liter/100km in China? 公里/公升？ 公升/100公里？

Tags: usage

In America we describe the fuel consumption of a car with miles/gallon. I know in some countries people use liters/100 km. Some countries use km/liter.

Which format do Chinese people use, L/100 km or km/L?

公里/公升？ 公升/100公里？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In China `升/百公里(L/100km)` is used as the measurement of [油耗](http://baike.bitauto.com/basictechparam/20120629/1405745326.html).

[image]

> 油耗：俗称汽车在行驶完100公里的耗油量。
>   耗油量参数是指汽车行驶百公里消耗的燃油量(以“升”「L」为计量单位)。

[ Oil consumption: Commonly known as the oil consumption for the car driving 100 kilometres.
The parameter of oil consumption is the consumed oil capacity for the car driving 100 kilometres (taking liter as the unit of measurement). ]

Comment: off topic: since fuel is literally called 油 (oil), what term is used to speak about engine oil? I always thought 油 refers to actual oil.

Comment: @DanieleD `机油` or `发动机润滑油`. And `油` could be used for `fat`, `grease` etc.

Comment: gasoline:汽油，diesel：柴油，engine oil：机油